# AngularJS Mobile-Nav AJAX calls blocked

Tags: ajax, angularjs, cordova

I've got an AngularJS app that I'm developing with Phonegap for an iOS app.

The App uses Angular-Mobile (ngMobile) and angular-mobile-nav: https://github.com/ajoslin/angular-mobile-nav

When the app loads, a home screen appears with a list of items from the database for the user to see. These are loaded from WebSQL, but on initial load should be downloaded from an API.

I'm using AngularJS' $http library to do the downloads:

```
$http.get(
        $scope.api_url + '/users/events/?values=' + hash,           
        {
            headers: {apihash: hashes.apihash}
        }
    ).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
        // do stuff with response
    }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){
        // log the error
    });
```

The problem I've got is that this API request does not complete until I tap on a link, and navigate to a new page - which is handled by angular-mobile-nav.

I can sit on the home screen for a minute, but as soon as I move to the new view I can see in the Console the AJAX call completing. The same thing happens on this screen, if I trigger an AJAX call, I can wait as long as I want, as soon as I switch back to my home screen I can see the AJAX call to the API complete in the console.

This is the code I've got setup to do my navigation:

```
ng-tap="slidePage('/catalogue')"
```

And my route provider looks like this:

```
$routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',   
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        }).
        when('/catalogue', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/catalogue.html', 
            controller: 'CatalogueCtrl',
        }).
        otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
```

The routing and the mobile-nav all works fine, I can switch between views with no problem, but the AJAX in the background is getting blocked or delayed by the UI till I move to the next view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have to apply the changes to the scope.

Have you tried this?

```
    $scope.$apply(function()
    {
       // do stuff with response
    });
```

Comment: Forgot about this question, you're right I'd not been calling $apply(), which I have since been doing.